# Cron Expression not working for minutes and seconds using c#

Tags: c#, cron

i given this format for minutes with seconds `("0/{0} 0/{1} * * * ?)` but this format taken every seconds and  every minutes. I need minutes with seconds core expression format

Comment: what do you mean "minutes with seconds"?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Can you be more specific and provide more details? [Ask]

Comment: You can use this for generating cron expressions https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: (0/2 0/3 0 ? * * *) this format also i am used but not working